# Subclassing a UIViewControllers View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

so for example i have this in my uiviewcontroller

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    MyDetailView *detailView = [[MyDetailView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.view = detailView;
    [detailView release];
}
```

now i add some labels to my view, f.e.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *descriptionLabel;
```

if i want to set this in my ViewController i would normally do something like

```
self.view.descriptionLabel.text = @"foo";
```

because this would generate a warning i cange it to

```
[[(MyDetailView*)self.view descriptionLabel] setText:@"foo"];
```

is there a better way for this? F.E. telling my ViewController that the view attribute is a subclass? is there a way for this or should i save my detail view in an additional ivar?

thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything wrong with what you've demonstrated. I might write it slightly differently, but that's probably a matter of preference:

```
myView = (MyDetailView *)[self view];
[myView setDescriptionLabel:@"foo"];
```

Comment: thank you. thought there is a "better" way. but if not, thats fine. just for interest, why do you prefer the code style `[self view]` instead of `self.view` (don't know how this styles are called) ?

Comment: i've pondered the same question, actually not when using a custom view but using for example a uitableview or uiscrollview as a view controller's view. the only reason i've written this way, and it really is just a matter of preference/clarity, is that I prefer not to mix dot accessors with bracketed/traditional accessors - tend to use one or the other in a given line of code, find that it reads a bit easier.

Comment: so setting a scrollview as the view would also be okay?

Comment: indeed yes you can use a scrollview!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written, it looks like you're setting a UILabel to an NSString value, so maybe this is just an edit. Have you tried

```
self.view.descriptionLabel.text = @"foo";
```

Comment: sure, you are right. this was no real code, so i forgot the attribute. thanks for this, updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

isaac's answer is great if you want to do it programmatically.  Just set up your custom view to be its own variable, so you can draw and pass information to and from it anywhere in the file.  This answer is merely an alternative to add to your options.  If you've done this in IB, the easiest way would be to select the view controller's View and set Class from the default `UIView` to your custom MyDetailView.  Then calling `self.view` will access the properties of your custom view directly.